# phpMyEdit old version add button not working

Tags: php

I have and old script, some phpMyEdit.class.php.

It was working until we had a server running php4, now we have moved to php5, and it doesn't working anymore.

I tried to figure out the problem, but without no luck.
I spent already 4 hours on it.

When I want to change, delete ,update, or add new record, it just refreshes the page, but nothing happens.

The default language is english,so the add button is add in the array also.

Anyone, please?

Thx

Comment: Normally I'd just use the read_brain() function, but I'm upgrading stuff right now. So can you please post some code? :)

Comment: So this is the old class file: http://pbboston.com/marketadmin/phpmyedit.clas.txt  and this is the lang file: http://pbboston.com/marketadmin/phpmyedit.clas.txt and this is a script using the class http://pbboston.com/marketadmin/show.txt

Comment: Can you post the relevant, brief section into your question please? You won't get any answers if people have to go through 3,200+ lines of code.

Comment: I find the solution, it was at line 2754, it was missing an ")", and it was getting called in just some few situations.

Comment: @pzoli89 - I have the same problem, phpMyEdit on PHP 5.4, the buttons only refresh the page - please let me know more details how you solve it. I could not see any problem in "phpMyEdit.class.php" line 2754. Thanks.

Comment: solved - I updated to "latest" phpMyAdmin and made some changes - http://opensource.platon.org/forum/projects/viewtopic.php?t=10785780

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the latest version (http://opensource.platon.sk/projects/download.php?project_id=5&package=phpMyEdit) and include that instead of the old version.